# `cryptsetup open` fails with correct passphrase - "No key available with this passphrase."

Tags: encryption, disk-encryption, btrfs, luks

I recently ran (essentially) `rm -rf / --no-preserve-root` on my LUKS encrypted BTRFS root filesystem. I'm trying to mount the drive from an endeavouros (arch) liveusb, without success.

I created a directory to mount in `/home/liveuser/m`, and am trying to open `/dev/nvme1n1p2` with the following command: `sudo cryptsetup open /dev/nvme1n1p2` followed by entering my passphrase. I have looked through many answers through SO, superuser, and Unix/Linux, but they all seem to be incorrect passphrases or hardware incompatibility; which is extremely unlikely because I am using the same hardware, the only difference being the liveusb. I *highly* doubt I am entering an incorrect passphrase for the following reasons:

my keyboard is, and always has been en_US qwerty

when I try to boot from the disk normally, grub(?) asks me for the passphrase and accepts it, outputting the following:

```
Attempting to decrypt master key...
Slot 0 opened
error: file `/@/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/normal.mod' not found.
Entering rescue mode...
```

any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be using an incorrect/incomplete command to open the volume.  Try this -

```
  sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/nvme1n1p2 decryptedblock
  sudo mount /dev/mapper/decryptedblock /mnt
```

(Change the mount point on the second command as appropriate).  I've now played around with it, and you could possibly replace the first command with *cryptsetup open --type luks /dev/nvme1n1p2 decryptedblock* )

When you are finished, you can  do

```
 sudo umount /mnt
 sudo luksClose decryptedblock
```